# How to authenticate users from sharepoint 2013 web service and active directory

Tags: java, android, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I authenticate users in a java android application using sharepoint 2013 and secondly how to authenticate users using active directory directly. I have to implement both the ways in two different applications.

I searched on Google but haven't found the proper ways to integrate them.

Comment: i have posted some link for reference you can try using that

Answer (score 0):

Azure provides an API for authentication for Microsoft Sharepoint. You can login using that else you can open webview for login of sharepoint. Then after login you can store cookies and you can use it as token in each webservice call.

For more detail about azure you can see this link .

[Azure API For Microsoft sharepoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication/)

[sample code for azure authentication](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-sharepoint)

If you want to login with webview then you can see this link below it helps you.
[Login with Webview](https://asheshany.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/connecting-to-sharepoint-2013-online-365-apis-in-android/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i want to auth users from my sharepoint 2013 users list, only users can access whom i have added to the sharepoint 2013 site.means user have to enter a user name and password. i am making a app in android and want to fetch all the data from sharepoint 2013 site, using restful api or web service provided by sharepoint 2013,  Plz help

Comment: @NikVarma dear you cant directly authenticate in sharepoint . there is no way like we custom login page and fire request on submit for login. that only possible when you use azure authentication. else there is not any other way . you can use webview for authentication that link i have provide you

Comment: ok, last i have one more quest, can i use sharepoint 2013 web service to auth users or by changing some setting in sharepoint 2013 to auth users. i founded the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx which have all the resource list

Comment: or can i make a custom sharepoint 2013 api and integrate with the sharepoint 2013 api to auth users and accessing the data. it's a good way or not. Plz help

Comment: Authentication can be done without Azure API by directly interacting with SharePoint web service or REST API.

Comment: @Vijay, Plz can you tell me, how can i make the same. Plz share code if possible

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper, Plz tell me how to make a "AsyncTask" class,
unable to understand after the below line of code First of all you need to put you code in an AsyncTask class, or it will give you a network error."https://asheshany.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/connecting-to-sharepoint-2013-online-365-apis-in-android/

Comment: @NikVarma everything written in this blog brother.you can see how to send request with which header.

Comment: @Vijay hello. can telll me how can i authenticate using rest in sharepoint without Azure API