# How to get sharepoint web service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new in sharepoint.
I want to create a user login in android application but i have to use a sharepoint 2013 web service to check the user login authentication.

and also want to know how can i get sharepoint 2013 web service URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to authenticate users from sharepoint 2013 web service and active directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589097/how-to-authenticate-users-from-sharepoint-2013-web-service-and-active-directory)

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 REST service - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

Comment: The question is a possible duplicate. The other question remains unanswered. The answer provided to the question is incorrect. Please upvote the other question to get a response.