# access sharepoint token when user login from the client android

Tags: java, android, api, sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint development, i done branding for sharepoint but not worked on sharepoint coding. Now i have a project in which i am making a android app using sharepoint 2013. basic idea is that i will access the sharepoint data from the sharepoint 2013 site and display into client android app and i am using java for the andoid but i am the getting the auth for sharepoint and token to access. I want a sharepoint token when user login from the client android application to access the list and data

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way you can get authentication token

1 > using Azure Api

2> using Webview you can login and get cookies after login.

for more info see this Link my answer. [How to authenticate users from sharepoint 2013 web service and active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589097/how-to-authenticate-users-from-sharepoint-2013-web-service-and-active-directory/38603701#38603701)

Comment: Thank you but Azure store credential on cloud, any other way to access the token when user enter the username and password from the client side androied app, our data is critical so we can not share or store on cloud

Comment: i have give other way. you can open login screen inside webview then login in web and get cookies after login

Comment: i have given link also to you check there .

Comment: yes, i checked but it's not working , don't know why, the reason i am asking the same quest. every time getting 401 error. if there any way to write web api in c share then it will also help full for me

Comment: brother i m working on that and i have make 3 app from this so its work well

Comment: ok, so please can you tell me the configuration you have done for the sharepoint 2013 and on IIS site with access level. Please share, may i have missed configure the site while creating

Comment: i dont know about side of sharepoint.so i  dont know you just have to put url to load login page in webview